# Query Error in ORMLite Update Raw

Tags: android, ormlite

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO temp_d_takingOrder(
    HeaderId,
    ItemCode,
    Qty1,
    Qty2,
    Qty3,
    RegDisc,
    ExtraDisc,
    OthersDisc,
    RegPerc,
    ExtraPerc,
    OthersPerc) 
SELECT 
    t._id, 
    m.itemCode,0 AS Qty1,
    0 AS Qty2,
    0 AS Qty3,
    0 AS RegDisc,
    0 AS ExtraDisc,
    0 AS OthersDisc,
    0 AS RegPerc,
    0 AS ExtraPerc,
    0 AS OthersPerc 
FROM m_Route AS m 
JOIN t_TakingOrder AS t ON 
    m.CustId = t.CustId **WHERE t.CustId=?"**;

dataTemp_d_TakingOrder.updateRaw(sql3);
```

When I used `WHERE t.CustId=?`, the query is not working. But if I delete that statements, the query is working.. can u help me?

Comment: you add a where clause and call `updateRaw` without providing any value

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Always provide exceptions and specific error messages.

Comment: That's probably the answer @mihail.  You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You add a where clause and call `updateRaw` without providing any value.